# How can I change KDE Plasma settings in NixOS?

Tags: kde, nixos, plasma

I know that NixOS likes to configure things itself, so I figure I'm just thinking about this in the wrong way. I'd like to, say, change the icons that are displayed in my system tray, but when I right-click and open the system tray settings, I get a small transparent window:

[image: Screenshot]

Is this a bug? Or do I have to configure Plasma settings in my configuration.nix file?

Comment: That sounds like a bug, and I don't think this can well be configured through `configuration.nix`, but I almost don't use Plasma...

Comment: I have the same issue on certain settings screens, using NixOS and Plasma. Any progress?

Comment: @Jonathan I run into similar issue a few times and the only solution for me was to reboot. After reboot the windows showed correctly.